# How do I style the Material-UI Menu Popover with JSS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, jss

I have a Code Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/0qv1jwlmlv

What I'm doing is pretty straight forward:

```
class SimpleMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <AppBar className={classes.root}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            aria-owns={anchorEl ? "simple-menu" : null}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Open Menu
          </Button>
          <Menu
            id="simple-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            PopoverClasses={{
              paper: classes.menu
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  root: {
    height: 100
  },
  menu: {
    position: "relative",
    top: 100
  }
};
export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleMenu);
```

Here, my navbar is of a fixed height, and when you press the menu button, I want the menu button to open below the nav bar.

To do this - I've added relative styling to the menu popover, and this style is applied to the popover paper - but the inline style that material applies to the popover takes over and it doesn't work.

How am I meant to style this?

Comment: Ah, ok, I see in the examples  there's a demo using the `Grow` component. I'll get on with posting an answer now.

Comment: Here's  a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/0xx1zp57np, but to be honest, i cbf right now writing up a full answer of what's going on with the solution. It's pretty convoluted imo.

Comment: If anyone is interested, here's a post I made about an abstracted menu button component I created https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205359/this-material-ui-menu-drop-down-component-i-created

Answer (score 13):

A year has passed, anyway. Add styles with PaperProps in this way.

Here is [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0x508?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
PaperProps={{
 style: {
  marginTop: "40px"
 }
}}
```